# Can't read data using TcpServer and TcpSocket

Tags: qt

I have a camera and want to send data to it but first I have to make a connexion between the camera's software (which is on my laptop) and my software so I need to open two sockets get data from.the software then send it to the camera.

**sockettest.h:**

```
class SocketTest : public QObject{

    Q_OBJECT
    public:
    explicit SocketTest(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    bool start_listen(int);
    QTcpSocket *blutechnix;
    QTcpSocket *tof;
    QTcpServer *server;
    void incomingConnection();
    signals:

    public slots:
    void Connect();
    private:
};


SocketTest::SocketTest(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent){

    server = new QTcpServer(this);
    connect(server, SIGNAL(newConnection()),this, SLOT(Connect()));
    tof = new QTcpSocket(this);
    tof->connectToHost("192.168.0.10",10001);
    if(tof->waitForConnected(3000))
     {
    qDebug() << "tof connected";


    if(server->listen(QHostAddress::LocalHost, 10000))
        {
            qDebug() << "Listening...";
            qDebug() << server->serverAddress();
            qDebug() << server->serverPort();
        }
    }
    else
        {
            qDebug() << "tof connexion failed";
        }
    tof->close();

    }


sockettest.h:

void SocketTest::Connect(){

    qDebug() << "CONNECTED";
    blutechnix = server->nextPendingConnection();
    blutechnix->waitForReadyRead();
    QByteArray array =blutechnix->read(blutechnix->bytesAvailable());
    qDebug() << array;
    //send all data to the camera
    tof->write(array);
    tof->waitForBytesWritten();
    //make sure that we wrote the right bytes
    tof->waitForReadyRead(3000);
    qDebug() << "Reading tof" << tof->bytesAvailable();
    qDebug() << tof->readAll();

}

void SocketTest::incomingConnection() {

    if( ! blutechnix->setSocketDescriptor(server->socketDescriptor()) ) {
    QMessageBox::warning( (QWidget *)this->parent(), tr("Error!"), tr("Socket 
    error!") );
    return;
    }
}
```

I run the code and I got as a result:

> tof connected
>    Listening...
>    QHostAddress<"127.0.0.1"> 10000

Why I can't see the data? why the `Connect()` function is not executed?
I hope you could help me.

Comment: What [Socket Error](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#error-1) is reported when you connect to the `error` signal?

Comment: change the port number to 80

Comment: Or scan the free port `QTcpSocket *socket = new QTcpSocket();
qint16 port = 80;
while(!socket->bind(port, QAbstractSocket::DontShareAddress))
{
  port++;
}`

Comment: but I need to listen to the port 10000!

Answer (score 0):

The server is listening out for a connection from localhost on port 10000. What you probably want is to connect to the `readyRead()` signal on `tof` and read data from there using `tof->readAll()`, and writing data using `tof.write(QByteArray)`.

You don't need a `QTcpServer` unless you have another program willing to make connections to you (i.e. you're the server.) That's the camera software's job.